# Polymer append listener declaratively to component

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-1.0

for some polymer components it is possible to add a listener by setting the name of the listener-function as an attribute of the component. For example:

```
<iron-signals on-iron-signal-foo="_fooChanged"></iron-signals>
```

I want to add this functionality to some of my components.

```
<x-foo on-foo-changed="_fooChanged">
```

Foo must not be variable like in the iron-signal component. But i have no idea how i execute a function of the host element by its name (as String).

Can anyone give me a hint or an example?

Thank You

Comment: did not really implement this before, but did you try by any chance to use something like `this.parentNode` inside `x-foo`? `this` being a reference to the x-foo element itself and `parentNode` a reference to the one that included it maybe?

Comment: thank you for your comment. but how can i execute a function by its string name?

Comment: Can you fire a custom event from inside your 'foo'? then the declarative listener in the form of `on-my-custom-event="_hostMethod"` will pick it up and call the method.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that it was pretty simple, as @Lukasz Mysiak suggested. You just need to fire a **custom event** with a certain name, like "*foo-changed*" in your example, and Polymer takes care of calling any method that was registered by adding an *on-foo-changed* property on the element.

Code I used to test this out:

I have this "parent" element:

```
    This is the parent
    <my-child on-correct-value="_handleCorrectValue"></my-child>

  </template>

  <script>
    class MyParent extends Polymer.Element {
      static get is() {
        return 'my-parent';
      }
      _handleCorrectValue(event) {
        console.log("in parent, got event", event);
      }
    }
    window.customElements.define(MyParent.is, MyParent);
  </script>
```

That uses this child element:

```
    <input on-keyup="_updateValue">

  </template>

  <script>

    class MyChild extends Polymer.Element {

      static get is() {
        return 'my-child';
      }

      _updateValue(event) {
        if (42 == event.currentTarget.value) {
          this.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('correct-value', { bubbles: true, composed: true, detail: { value: 42 } }));
        }
      }
    }
```

*(I hope it's pretty obvious I left some parts out to keep the answer short)*

And when using the  element in a page, every time I type "*42*" into the input from , the **_handleCorrectValue** method from the parent is being called.

Reference: https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/devguide/events

Important: don't forget to set **bubbles: true, composed: true** on the event!